# Joining nearest points to make line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a dataset containing nearly 200 points.

Is there a tool for joining nearest points to make a multiline in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Use the plugin PointsToPaths.

http://spatialgalaxy.net/2011/12/30/qgis-plugin-of-the-week-points-to-paths/